# "Know" and "know not"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I don't recognise the name Herb Sutter.

> - I don't know him.
> - I know him not.

What's the difference?

Comment: *I know him not* is an archaic construction that is still occasionally used in this set phrase. *I don't know him* would be modern English usage.

Comment: @Peter Shor: You should have just put that in as an answer. Maybe no-one else will answer because they can't think of anything useful to add to what you've said.

Comment: Three downvotes with no reasons?

Comment: @Dusty: before the question was rewritten, it was close to incomprehensible. I suspect that is the source of the downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of meaning, there is no difference.

"I know him not" is an archaic, or out of fashion, way of saying it.  It wouldn't be incorrect to say that, even now, and some people might do so out of stylistic reasons (or something else).  Everyone will understand.  However, it's the old way of saying it, and most people wouldn't say it that way.